# Prove that $|\sin 1| + |\sin 2| + |\sin 3| +\cdots+ |\sin 3n| > 8n/5$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, summation

So, the question is as follows:

Prove that $\left|\sin 1\right| + \left|\sin 2\right| + \left|\sin 3\right| +\cdots+ \left|\sin 3n\right| > 8n/5.$

I have tried quite a few approaches, including using the Taylor expansion or the A.M-G.M inequality, but to no avail. It would be of great help if this problem could be proven.

Edit: Angles are in radians, $n$ is a natural number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lemma: The function

$$f(x)=|\sin(x)|+|\sin(x+1)|+\sin(x+2)|>\frac{8}{5}$$

for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Proof: It suffices to show that the above equation holds for $x\in [0,2\pi]$. The function is piecewise differentiable except for

$$x\in \{0,\pi,\pi-1,2\pi-1,\pi-2,2\pi-2,2\pi\}$$

Then $f(x)$ can be rewritten

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 
      f_1(x)=\sin(x)+\sin(x+1)+\sin(x+2) & 0\leq x\leq \pi-2 \\
      f_2(x)=\sin(x)+\sin(x+1)-\sin(x+2) & \pi-2\leq x\leq \pi-1 \\
\vdots \\
      f_6(x)=-\sin(x)+\sin(x+1)+\sin(x+2) & 2\pi-1\leq x\leq 2\pi
   \end{cases}$$

We can then take each of these intervals and prove $f_i(x)>\frac{8}{5}$. For $i=1$, we have

$$f_1(x)=\sin(x)+\sin(x+1)+\sin(x+2)$$

$$=-\sin ^2(1) \sin (x)+\sin (x)+\cos ^2(1) \sin (x)+2 \sin (1) \cos (1)
   \cos (x)+\sin (1) \cos (x)+\cos (1) \sin (x)$$

Note that

$$f_1(0)=\sin (1)+2 \sin (1) \cos (1)>\left(1-\frac{1}{3!}\right)+2\left(1-\frac{1}{3!}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{2!}\right)=\frac{5}{3}>\frac{8}{5}$$

$$f_1(\pi-2)=\sin (1)+\sin (2)>\left(1-\frac{1}{3!}\right)+\left(2-\frac{2^3}{3!}+\frac{2^5}{5!}-\frac{2^7}{7!}\right)=\frac{1097}{630}>\frac{8}{5}$$

(we have used the Taylor series expansions to get bounds for $\sin(1),\sin(2)$, and $\cos(1)$). Thus, at the endpoints of $[0,\pi-2]$ we know $f_1(x)>\frac{8}{5}$. Now, taking the derivative we get

$$f_1^{'}(x)=\cos (x)+\cos (x+1)+\cos (x+2)=(1+2 \cos (1)) \cos (x+1)$$

This is easily solved and we see that the only zero on the interval $[0,\pi-2]$ is $x=\frac{\pi }{2}-1$. The final step is to take the derivative one more time:

$$f_1^{''}(x)=-(1+2 \cos (1)) \sin (x+1)$$

Since

$$\cos(1)>1-\frac{1}{2!}=\frac{1}{2}>0$$

we know

$$f_1^{''}(x)=-(1+2 \cos (1)) \sin (x+1)<0$$

for $x\in [0,\pi-2]$. Putting it all together, we have

$$f_1(0)>\frac{8}{5}$$

$$f_1(\pi-2)>\frac{8}{5}$$

$$f_1^{'}(x)\text{ has a single zero on the interval}$$

$$f_1^{''}(x)<0\text{ on the interval}$$

These conditions imply that $f_1(x)>\frac{8}{5}$ for all $x\in[0,\pi-2]$. The remaining cases can be proven in much the same manner as the $i=1$ case. With this, the lemma is proved.

Theorem: The finite sum

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \bigg(|\sin(3i+1)|+|\sin(3i+2)|+|\sin(3i+3)|\bigg)>\frac{8}{5}n$$

Proof: By the lemma (with $x=3i-1$), we know that each portion of the sum is greater than $\frac{8}{5}$. Then

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \bigg(|\sin(3i+1)|+|\sin(3i+2)|+|\sin(3i+3)|\bigg)>\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{8}{5}=\frac{8}{5}n$$

and the theorem is proved.

EDIT: I included this after doing some numerical examples. It seems that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \bigg(|\sin(3i+1)|+|\sin(3i+2)|+|\sin(3i+3)|\bigg)=1.9098...$$

One point, this kinda looks like a Riemann sum (at least the fraction out in front of a finite sum). Second point, if the limit really does exist then the conjecture is true for all but a finite number of $n$ for all $x<1.9098...$. That is, if $x<1.9098...$ then for all but a finite number of $n$

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \bigg(|\sin(3i+1)|+|\sin(3i+2)|+|\sin(3i+3)|\bigg)>xn$$

It just so happens that $\frac{8}{5}$ is not a tight bound. In fact, a tighter bound which should work for all $n$ is $\frac{42}{25}$. That is

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \bigg(|\sin(3i+1)|+|\sin(3i+2)|+|\sin(3i+3)|\bigg)>\frac{42}{25}n$$

is true for all $n$. Proving this would just require a lot more terms of the Taylor series expansions of $\sin(1),\cos(1),$ and $\sin(2)$ (or some other expansion).

EDIT 2: Last edit, I realized that the limit up there (in EDIT 1) **is** similar to a Riemann sum. Specifically

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \bigg(|\sin(x)|+|\sin(x+1)|+|\sin(x+2)|\bigg)dx=\frac{12}{2\pi}=\frac{6}{\pi}=1.90986...$$

which is what the limit seemed to converge to. It would take some finess (you would probably have to use the fact that the natural numbers are equidistributed modulo $2\pi$), but I am now confident that the limit above really does exist and that it is equal to $\frac{6}{\pi}$.

Comment: Very nice solution !

Comment: Jesus! Thank you so much. I really love the fact that you fine tuned the limit when n tends to infinity! Thank you so much!

Comment: I did some further research and a proof of that fact is not even that difficult (although it uses some heavy machinery). Basically just use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem and the result follows.